# If that possible to record and repeat what have done by user at any website with selenium webdriver C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

(Without using selenium IDE)

May I know is that possible if I want develop a software that will repeat back what was user done before this in a website?

For example: user had click a button and insert text into textbox in a website. May I know how can I repeat back what was user done just know with using c#.

My Logic:
Can I get the ID of web element that was used/clicked by user in a website with using c# without view to the source code of that website so after that I can use back the ID to repeat the actions that had done by user just now?

Comment: is this supposed to be some kind of keylogger?

Comment: similar, but mostly focus on the web elements.

Comment: You could add an OnChanged/OnKeyPress/OnSeletedIndexChanged (and event for every control) and attach it via Ajax to a method that stores the action based on control type. To "play it back," simply perform each stored command with a delay from a background thread, Invoking each change. What types of controls are on the page you want to monitor?

Comment: Have a look at EventFiringWebDriver and WebDriverEventListener. The listener exposes many methods which you can override and log actions.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger is that only work on window form?

Comment: @Grasshopper either one also can?

Comment: @tenkeason, my answer was tailored to WinForm, but you could do the same thing with WPF or with console app.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger sorry I'm confused about how to use the(OnChanged/OnKeyPress/OnSeletedIndexChanged ) for the web element. As I know and I found at online,  it only work on window form not web. May you explain more or maybe I got something wrong info.

Comment: Ok - are you developing a web project? Let's be clear there first. This is webForm not WinForm, correct?

Comment: @tenkeason I did not understand your comment. Please explain...